# No Contact Role related list on Contact?

Tags: contact, related-list, roles, teams

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious here, but on an Account layout I can add Contact Roles fine. Now if I want to view this from a Contact point of view (ie see what roles a Contact plays in several Accounts) I'd expect to see a similar related list available on the Contact layout.

It isn't there.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Is it simply that the contact roles related list isn't displayed on the contact layout?  Have you tried adding it to page layout?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Looking now.

Answer (score 1):

We have only following three types of Team:

1. [Account Team](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accountteam_def.htm&language=en_US)
2. [Opportunity Team](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=salesteam_def.htm&language=en_US)
3. [Case team](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=caseteam_def.htm&language=en_US)

But not Contact Team.

[There is Idea open for this where you can vote.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YCpRAAW)

Comment: Doesn't quite seem to be the same thing. Account Teams are Users who work together on an Account. Contact Roles describe how a Contact (not User) interacts with an Account.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not allow us to add related list on Contact to show where it is part of Contact Role.

You have the option to either build a custom related list in LWC/Aura/VF Page or install the [CMTD Enhanced Related List](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYDY4UAP) app and configure it for your use case.

There is a video here on how to setup and configure the app :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5p9wljcwdM0&t=694s